# How to restart a killed actor?

Tags: scala, akka

I have a supervisor and a child actor that looks as the following:

SupervisorActor.scala

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, Props, Terminated}

object SupervisorActor {

  def props: Props = Props(new SupervisorActor)

  object KillFoo
  object TerminateFoo
  object RestartFoo

}

final class SupervisorActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  import com.sweetsoft.SupervisorActor._

  log.info(s"Start the actor ${self}")

  private val foo = context.actorOf(FooActor.props, "FOOCHILD")

  context.watch(foo)

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case KillFoo =>
      context.stop(foo)
    case Terminated(actor) =>
      log.info(s"Kill actor $actor")
    case TerminateFoo =>
      log.info("Terminate FooActor")
      foo ! new IllegalArgumentException
    case RestartFoo =>
  }
}
```

FooActor.scala

```
import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.{Escalate, Restart, Resume, Stop}
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, OneForOneStrategy, Props}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object FooActor {
  def props: Props = Props(new FooActor)
}

final class FooActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  log.info(s"Start the actor ${ self }")

  override val supervisorStrategy: OneForOneStrategy =
    OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 1, withinTimeRange = 1.minute) {
      case _: ArithmeticException => Resume
      case _: NullPointerException => Restart
      case _: IllegalArgumentException =>
        println("STOP exception raised.")
        Stop
      case _: Exception => Escalate
    }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _ => log.info("I got killed.")
  }
}
```

and Main.scala

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import com.sweetsoft.SupervisorActor.{TerminateFoo}

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.io.StdIn

object Main extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("monarch")
  implicit val dispatcher = system.dispatcher

  try {
    // Create top level supervisor
    val supervisor = system.actorOf(SupervisorActor.props, "mupervisor")
    // Exit the system after ENTER is pressed
    Future {
     Thread.sleep(2000)
      supervisor ! TerminateFoo
    }

    StdIn.readLine()
  } finally {
    system.terminate()
  }

}
```

After the `FooActor` got killed, I would like to restart it manually again, like I did:

```
private val foo = context.actorOf(FooActor.props, "FOOCHILD")
```

How to do it?

I am thinking about to create a function, that is going to create the `FooActor` and after it got killed, just call the function to start a new `FooActor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code. `supervisorStrategy` should be in the `SupervisorActor` as it is responsible for supervision, not the child actor itself.

`foo ! new IllegalArgumentException` won't cause the child actor to terminate as actors can accept any object as a message and Exception derived objects are not treated specially. It'll just print "I got killed." but otherwise ignore the message and keep running. In particular, it won't invoke supervisorStrategy 
handler.

You can either:

- send the pre-defined system `PoisonPill` message to the child actor
  to gracefully stop it (i.e. after processing all pending messages)
- send the pre-defined system `Kill` message to the child actor to stop
  it immediately after processing the current message and ignore the
  other queued messages if any.
- forward `TerminateFoo` message to it
  and throw an exception in its handler. In this case the child
  object's destiny is decided by supervisorStrategy handler for
  IllegalArgumentException exception type (i.e. Stop in your case).

.

```
override def receive: Receive = {
    case TerminateFoo =>
      log.info("Stopping FooActor by throwing an unhandled exception for supervisorStrategy to process it")
      throw new IllegalArgumentException
    case m => log.info(s"I received a message $m")
  }
```

See https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#stopping-actors for details

Comment: I forgot to mention that 'context.watch(foo)' is also unnecessary as parent actors watch all their child actors automatically. See https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/supervision.html

Comment: First of all, thank a lot for your response. I changed and could you please review it https://gitlab.com/akka-samples/playactor, if I did it correctly or not.

Comment: could you please try it again.

Comment: @zero_coding I think you need to create a Merge Request there in order to be able to add code review comments